# Merge Two Tables with Exact Data Distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I'm working with SQL Server.

I need to join two tables based on the "Ctrl" column. The first table, "Cad_Clients", contains client information, while the second one, "Cad_Colors", has descriptions of the information. The condition for joining them is that the value of "Ctrl" must be the same in both tables. However, the distribution needs to be exact, meaning that duplicates cannot occur.

Imagine that I create a 'for' loop in the 'Cad_Colors' table. In each iteration, I add a record from the table to 'Cad_Clients' as long as the 'Ctrl' value matches. Afterward, I delete that record from 'Cad_Colors'. If the looped table becomes empty or the loop reaches its end, it means that I have distributed as many records as possible. That's all, but I don't want to use a loop in the database; I'm confident that by discussing it here, we can achieve a much more concise result.

Visual depiction of the issue:

[image: Visual depiction of the issue]

Cad_Clients

```
| idPerson | Person         | Ctrl  |
|----------|----------------|-------|
| 1        | John           | 100   |
| 2        | Sarah          | 101   |
| 3        | Michael        | 102   |
| 4        | Emily          | 103   |
| 5        | William        | 104   |
| 6        | Olivia         | 105   |
| 7        | James          | 100   |
| 8        | Emma           | 101   |
| 9        | Benjamin       | 102   |
| 10       | Sophia         | 103   |
| 11       | Samuel         | 104   |
| 12       | Ava            | 105   |
| 13       | Joseph         | 100   |
```

Cad_Colors

```
| Ctrl | Color    | idColor |
|------|----------|---------|
| 100  | Red      | 1       |
| 104  | Blue     | 2       |
| 105  | Green    | 3       |
| 103  | Yellow   | 4       |
| 104  | Purple   | 5       |
| 105  | Red      | 6       |
```

Combining both tables:

```
| idPerson | Person  | Ctrl | Color  |
|----------|---------|------|--------|
| 1        | John    | 100  | Red    |
| 4        | Emily   | 103  | Yellow |
| 5        | William | 104  | Blue   |
| 6        | Olivia  | 105  | Green  |
| 11       | Samuel  | 104  | Purple |
| 12       | Ava     | 105  | Red    |
```

Some unsuccessful attempts:

```sql
INSERT INTO @Tmp
SELECT ccl.idPerson, ccl.Person, ccl.Ctrl, 
(SELECT TOP 1 cco.idColor FROM Cad_Colors cco WHERE cco.Ctrl = ccl.Ctrl AND cco.idColor NOT IN(SELECT idColor FROM @Tmp))
FROM Cad_Clients ccl
```

```sql
INSERT INTO @Tmp
SELECT ccl.idPerson, ccl.Person, ccl.Ctrl, cco.idColor, cco.Color
FROM Cad_Clients ccl
JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 cco.* FROM Cad_Colors cco WHERE cco.idColor NOT IN(SELECT idColor FROM @Tmp)) cco ON cco.Ctrl = ccl.Ctrl
```

```sql
INSERT INTO @Tmp
SELECT ccl.idPerson, ccl.Person, ccl.Ctrl, cco.idColor, cco.Color
FROM Cad_Clients ccl
JOIN Cad_Colors cco ON cco.Ctrl = ccl.Ctrl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Tmp WHERE Ctrl = cco.Ctrl)
```

```sql
MERGE INTO Cad_Clients AS target
USING Cad_Colors AS source
ON target.Ctrl = source.Ctrl
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET target.idPerson = target.idPerson
OUTPUT inserted.idPerson, inserted.Person, inserted.Ctrl, inserted.idColor, inserted.Color INTO @tmp;
```

Assistance in creating the scenarios:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Cad_Clients( [idPerson] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Person] [varchar](60) NULL, [Ctrl] [int] NULL );
CREATE TABLE Cad_Colors( [Ctrl] [int] NULL, [Color] [varchar](60) NULL, [idColor] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO Cad_Clients (Person, Ctrl) VALUES ('John',100), ('Sarah',101), ('Michael',102), ('Emily',103), ('William',104), ('Olivia',105), ('James',100), ('Emma',101), ('Benjamin',102), ('Sophia',103), ('Samuel',104), ('Ava',105), ('Joseph',100);
INSERT INTO Cad_Colors (Ctrl, Color) VALUES (100, 'Red'), (104, 'Blue'), (105, 'Green'), (103, 'Yellow'), (104, 'Purple'), (105, 'Red');
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE( idPerson INT, Person VARCHAR(60), Ctrl INT, idColor INT /*Color VARCHAR(60)*/ );
```

Comment: is colors always shorter than clients, and will every color always find a client?

Comment: Not always! The number of colors may be sufficient for all clients (if the Ctrl condition is met). The client table may also be smaller than the colors table. The quantity of records is irrelevant; what really matters is that they are distributed as I mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately, "MERGE" isn't actually a relational algebra operation, so this will be difficult. I've come close, but it doesn't consume the clients as it goes: https://dbfiddle.uk/KCzhhrhY

Answer (score 2):

This should be a simple ROW_NUMBER join:

```sql
WITH persons AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (1, N'John', 100)
        ,   (2, N'Sarah', 101)
        ,   (3, N'Michael', 102)
        ,   (4, N'Emily', 103)
        ,   (5, N'William', 104)
        ,   (6, N'Olivia', 105)
        ,   (7, N'James', 100)
        ,   (8, N'Emma', 101)
        ,   (9, N'Benjamin', 102)
        ,   (10, N'Sophia', 103)
        ,   (11, N'Samuel', 104)
        ,   (12, N'Ava', 105)
        ,   (13, N'Joseph', 100)
    ) t (idPerson,Person,Ctrl)
)
, colors AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (100, N'Red', 1)
        ,   (104, N'Blue', 2)
        ,   (105, N'Green', 3)
        ,   (103, N'Yellow', 4)
        ,   (104, N'Purple', 5)
        ,   (105, N'Red', 6)
    ) t (Ctrl,Color,idColor)
)
SELECT  p.idPerson, p.Person, p.Ctrl, c.Color
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY ctrl ORDER BY idperson) AS sort
    FROM    persons c
    ) p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY ctrl ORDER BY idcolor) AS sort
    FROM    colors
    ) c
    ON  c.Ctrl = p.Ctrl
    AND c.sort = p.sort
```

You create a counter for every person grouped by Ctrl like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY ctrl ORDER BY idperson)` and do the same for the Colors, and then join on them together.

Output:

| idPerson | Person | Ctrl | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 100 | Red |
| 4 | Emily | 103 | Yellow |
| 5 | William | 104 | Blue |
| 11 | Samuel | 104 | Purple |
| 6 | Olivia | 105 | Green |
| 12 | Ava | 105 | Red |

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about this Row_Number function. It's really cool for creating unique association IDs within the conditions that join the two tables. Thanks for the help, seriously, I'm just starting out with SQL Server and I get a bit lost.

Comment: Yeah, it was a game changer when added a while ago! Glad it worked for you. Btw, if the answer helped, you can "approve it" by clicking on some button, so it becomes green

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution. You can make use of row_number window function to achieve this.

```
select 
        a.idPerson , 
        a.Person ,
        a.Ctrl , 
        b.Color 
    from
    (select * , row_number () over(partition by Ctrl order by idPerson) as cad_person_seq from Cad_Clients) 
    as a inner join
    (select * , row_number () over(partition by Ctrl order by idColor) as cad_color_seq from Cad_Colors) as b 
    on a.Ctrl = b.Ctrl and a.cad_person_seq = b.cad_color_seq
    order by a.cad_person_seq , a.Ctrl;
```